# Audio not working in Android webview

Tags: android, audio, webview

I open a website `URL` in Android `WebView` inside an application. One of the web pages contains links to Images and Audio files on server. Server in response reads the file requested and writes the content to `Response` stream and sets appropriate `Content-Type`. The images is opening perfectly but audio is not playing, it just flashes a window with the `URL` and just goes away immediately. I am using Java Script `window.open()` for this purpose.

When I access the website directly in Android browser, its playing the sound by opening native music player application. I am wondering why the same is not working inside `WebView`.

Do anybody have idea about such kind of problem? If you have further query on the same, I will provide. Please share your experience.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be specific. What version of Android? What phone are you testing on? What browser are you using that it works on?

Comment: Thanks Pieces! I am using Samsung Galaxy Y with Android 2.3.6. I think when we are using `WebView` its the default functionality of Android and for direct testing of website, I used default browser, which upon hitting the sound link gives option to play with native music player apps.

Comment: Any hint on how do I debug the problem? Is it `Java Script -> window.open()` that could be the culprit? Why different phone behaves differently for Android `WebView`. `Java Script` is already enabled as an image is opening successfully using same procedure. Its working on **Intex XOLO (ICS)** phone while not working on **Samsung Galaxy (2.3.6)**. Thanks.

Comment: Just to let you know that the problem is solved automatically and I am closing this question as it was working on the next day, may be the issue could be due to `Wi-Fi` connection accessing the local network server. When it was not working it was flashing the window appeared to open the `URL` and disappeared immediately without going further at the point of opening Media Player to play the requested audio file. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug inside the webview. you can use video tag replaced to audio tag as an example:

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="audio.mp3" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```